# An example of a particular vn-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a  vn-algebra. Let us suppose $e$ is a **finite projection** in $A$ and $x$ is an **isometry** (meaning $x^*x=1$) in $A$ such that $e$ does not commute with $x$. Then $\{q_n=x^nex^{*n}\}$ forms a sequence of pairwise different  **finite projections**.

> Q. Does there exist any vn-algebra in which one may find such a pair $(x,e)$ aforementioned above, such that $\inf_{1\leq n\leq N} q_n\neq0$ for all every natural number $N$?

Comment: Try finding operators on $\ell^2$

Comment: Clearly, $q_n$s are pairwise equivalent. Thus, in this case  dim$q_n(\ell^2)$'s are all the same.  It seems then the infimum should be zero for some $N$, does not it?

Comment: Why cannot $q_n(\ell^2)$ all be the same?

Comment: Certainly $q_n\neq q_m$ when $n\neq m$,  otherwise $x$ commutes with $e$.

Comment: There certainly are lots of different projections with the same range: say, various unitary conjugates

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't understand your last comment. A (orthogonal) projection is uniquely determined by its range.

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, mine was a stupid comment